# UDPClient stream is slightly delayed. Can I speed it up?

Tags: c#, performance, udp

So I have 2 C# applications running on the same machine. They communicate via UDPClient (one application opens the streams and sets it like this:

```
udp1Server.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, SocketOptionName.ReuseAddress, true);
```

The other application can connect and communicate messages at an acceptable rate, the only issue is that there is a slight delay of maybe half a second before it is recieved on the other app.

Seeing as these are communicating messages on the same machine there should be almost no lag right?

The funny this is that messages are actually being send from smartphone via bluetooth to app 1, then via udp to app 2. And the bluetooth stream is faster than the communication between 2 apps on the same machine?!

This is the application that sends the data:

```
static void UnityThread()
    {
        try
        {
            while (true)
            {
                if (bluetoothClients[0].Connected)
                {
                     byte[] sendBuf = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(latestData[0]);
                     udp1Server.Send(sendBuf, sendBuf.Length);
                }
                Thread.Sleep(1);
            }
        }

        catch (SocketException e) { }
    }
```

This is the application that receives the data:

```
void ConsoleThread(){
    while (!_isQuitting)
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] receiveBytes = udp1Server.Receive(ref localpt1);
            string returnData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receiveBytes);

            udpLastValue = returnData;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            print("errir in UDP1 " + e.ToString());
        }
        Thread.Sleep(1);
    }
}
```

Thanks a bunch

Comment: Your code has a bug, post the code. Also, there is no "stream" with UDP. Also, even on the local machine you can experience packet loss.

Comment: @usr Thanks for looking. Code has been posted

Comment: I would expect 30ms delay here. Sleep(1) usually is rounded up to 15ms. How are you reading udpLastValue and displaying it? The delay might be there.

Comment: The problem was the sleep in the receiver. I guess there is no point in having a sleep there because the sending rate is capped anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it up removing the sleep on the reciever.